# Set a fixed 0 to 100 range for a plotted line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is it possible to change a plotted indicator line so that it will always fluctuate in an exact range, say 0 to 100 ?

As an example, here is this basic script that plots the difference between a stock closing in green, or in red.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My indicator")

var n = 0

if (close > close[1])
    n += 1
else
    n -= 1

plot (n)
```

No matter what stock symbol you use, the script should always plot an 'n' variable with with an all-time low of 0, and an all-time high of 100.

Any ideas, please?

Thank you!

Alex

Comment: See [How can I rescale an indicator from one scale to another?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-rescale-an-indicator-from-one-scale-to-another)

Comment: Thank you, Bjorn! The 'normalize' function seems to be the one I need, but there is a problem: the shape of the plotted line is very much changed compared to the original line. Here's the code (to simplify things, I used 'close' as data source):

Comment: `//@version=5
indicator('My indicator')

normalize (_src, _min, _max) =>
    var _historicMin = 10e10
    var _historicMax = -10e10
    _historicMin := math.min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
    _historicMax := math.max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
    _min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / math.max (_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)

plot (normalize(close, 0, 100))`

Comment: If you also use the 'plot (close)' instruction at the end of the script, you will quickly see the difference between the two plotted lines. I believe this is because the 'math.min/max' functions do not read the all-time low and high. I am saying this because I hardcoded the two values myself (for 'META' symbol: _historicMin := 18, _historicMax := 379), and the normalized line did look exactly as the original line, only with a low of 0 and high of 100. Any idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: I hope the 'normalize' function is able to read the all-time low/high of a series variable and then change all its values to reflect the new low/high. Obviously, the shape of the line should not be changed at all in comparison to the original line. Only the values.

Comment: I think that what you're trying can't be done in Pine, because there's no way I know of to get the highest/lowest value of the entire dataset on beforehand. It would be futile too, because as time progresses, a higher high / lower low could be made, rendering the scaling on previous bars useless.

Comment: I understand. My ultimate goal is to merge some indicator lines into a single line. It is of course imperative that all the component lines use the same scale (their values are very much different), otherwise, the resulted single line will not give the most accurate representation of all the underlying lines. Question: is there any other way to achieve this? I am asking, because as it stands now, this is simply not possible (because of Pine's technical limitations). Hopefully, at some point, Pine Script will introduce a function that will make such a basic thing possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get a number in the specific range, you can add the range as a condition to the `if` statement:

```
var n = 0

if (close > close[1]) and n < 100
    n += 1
else if (close <= close[1]) and n > 0
    n -= 1

plot (n)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but what I am looking for is a way to rescale a plotted line and preserve its shape at the same time. I need this because I would like to merge some indicator lines into a single line, but to do that it is important to have a unique scale for all the component lines. I would like to do this at Pine Script level, not using any of TradingView's GUI tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the smallest `n` has ever been and the highest `n` has ever been, you can then place the current `n` between those two values.

Let's say the **smallest** `n` has ever been is **2** and the **highest** `n` has been **4**. Then if the current `n` would be **2** it would plot **0**, if it was **3** it would plot **50** and if it was **4** it would plot **100**

You can use a **linear function** to place the current `n` between the smallest `n` and the highest `n`. I use the variable `k` to keep track of the linear functions angle and `m` for the y-axis intersection value.

This is an image of the indicator, as you can see it moves fast up and down in the beginning because there is not a big difference between the smallest `n` and the highest `n`.

[image: image of indicator]
Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("min max, up down")

maxPlot = 100
minPlot = 0

var n = 0
var min = n
var max = n

//Update n
if (close > close[1])
    n += 1
else
    n -= 1

//Update min max
if(n > max)
    max := n
else if(n < min)
    min := n

k = (maxPlot - minPlot) / (max - min) //Angle = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
m = minPlot - (min * k) //y intersection = y1 - (x1 * k)

plot(n*k+m, color=color.green)
//plot (n)
//plot(min)
//plot(max)
```

Comment: Marcus, thank you for taking the time to write this code, but I am afraid it is not what I am looking for. Its main problem is that it is changing the shape of the plotted line. I am looking for a solution that will preserve the original shape of the line, and only change its values. That's it! For example, if I have an uptrending line with a low at 50 and a high at 200, the rescaled line should look **exactly** the same (uptrending), only with a low at 0 and a high at 100. As for all the other values of the line, each of them should be recalculated based on the new low and high.

Comment: I think this can be achieved using the 'normalize' function, but there is still an issue I have with that code (see my answer to Bjorn's comment, above). There is also the 'rescale' function, but for that you need to know the low and the high from the very beginning, which is not the case here (they vary depending on the symbol you use).

Answer (score 0):

We can pick up limited range high and low of n and draw lines of them.
Then we can adjust the line y1 and y2 (to be in range 0 to 100) at the last bar after known high and low of n.

```
//@version=5
indicator("High/Low Oscillator By Rohit",max_bars_back=5000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)

var hi=-99999
var lo=99999
var n=0
var cnt=1
var mininc=5
var n1=0.0
var n2=0.0
var n3=0.0
var bi=0

if (close > close[1])
    n += 1
else if (close < close[1])
    n -= 1
else
    n:=n+0
plot(n) //Actual 

if n>hi
    hi:=n
if n<lo
    lo:=n


    
var osc1 = array.new_line(10000, na)
var liney1=array.new_float(10000, na)
var liney2=array.new_float(10000, na)

n1:=ta.highest(n,20)
n2:=ta.lowest(n,20)


if n1[10]==n[20] and n1[10]>n1
    array.set(osc1,cnt,line.new(bi,n3,bar_index-20,n1[20]))
    array.set(liney1,cnt,n3)
    array.set(liney2,cnt,n1[20])
    n3:=n1[20]
    bi:=bar_index-20
    cnt:=cnt+1


if n2[20]==n[20] and n2[20]<n2
    array.set(osc1,cnt,line.new(bi,n3,bar_index-20,n2[20]))
    array.set(liney1,cnt,n3)
    array.set(liney2,cnt,n2[20])
    n3:=n2[20]  
    cnt:=cnt+1
    bi:=bar_index-20

   
//Adjust all line y coordinates
if(barstate.islast)
    gap=(hi-lo)/100
    for i = 1 to cnt-1
        line.set_y1(array.get(osc1,i),(array.get(liney1,i)-lo)/gap)
        line.set_y2(array.get(osc1,i),(array.get(liney2,i)-lo)/gap)
```

[image]